# Android Screen Orientations:

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

[image]

[image]

These orientations are shown correctly here, but when i run it and changes the orientations the landscape mode doesn't works and all the buttons are misplaced as[image]

what might the solution to this problem be?
XML for landscape mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/flowers"
android:id="@+id/frontpage_layout"

                              tools:context="com.example.hassidiczaddic.multiplescreensupport.MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="OPEN"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/button.open"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="LARGE"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/button.large"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="86dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button.rate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button.rate" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"

    android:text="Something"
    android:id="@+id/button.something"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button.open"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button.rate"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button.rate" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RATE"
    android:id="@+id/button.rate"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button.something"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button.open"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button.open" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLOSE"
    android:id="@+id/button.close"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button.something"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button.large"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button.large"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button.rate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button.rate" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the eclipse tag for?

Comment: If they have to look differently, then make 2 layouts. One for portrait mode and one for landscape.

Comment: I have made two xml layouts for them...

Comment: instead of posting images please post codes

Comment: Or post both the images of what you get and what you want AND the layout code for both the layouts.

Answer (score 4):

There are **6** different layout for the main activity, where the OS will select one most suitable for the current device in accordance to the qualifiers specified for each XML layout, the rules are defined [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Since you've provided layout for `small`/`normal`/`large` screen sizes, these layout will take priority over your `land` layout. In fact, the only time your `land` layout will be used is when you run it on a `xlarge` screen, since it's only then that layouts defined in `layout-land` will be used (check the link above for more detail).

You can fix this by either:

1. Remove `layout-small`/`layout-normal`/`layout-large`, then OS have nothing better to use than the one provided in `layout-port` & `layout-land`, note that the use of `layout-small`/`layout-normal`/`layout-large` have been strongly discouraged for years now, you should check the [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article.
2. Instead of using `layout-port` & `layout-land`, use the *Available height* qualifier (`layout-hXXXdp`) where XXX is the minimum height where you want this layout to be applied. For example `layout-h320dp` can contain the layout for phone on portrait mode, and put the side-by-side version of the layout XML in the default folder (`layout`).
3. Rework your UI design so none of the above is needed, perhaps by putting the buttons in a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: i have included a scroll view as a parent of relative layout but still output is same. my xml file is above please have a look about it.

Comment: @Nirojthapa I don't think your layout is valid, it's referencing non-existing id/button.rate

Comment: @+id/button.rate is the id of Button RATE

Comment: @Nirojthapa have you removed layout-small/layout-normal/layout-large? If not then layouts from those directories will be used.

Answer (score 1):

As per your Images shows that you have used **RelativeLayout** and because No room is available for the buttons so it is overlapping and misplacing.

Better you use **ScrollView** as parent of **RelativeLayout** else you have to resize button dynamically by calculating height of the screen and all that parameters.

Comment: I  have used Scroll view as a parent of Relativelayout but this also does't works.

Comment: @Nirojthapa can you post your xml in question so might help more specifically.

Comment: I have added the xml..please have a word for it.

Comment: @Nirojthapa add android:orientation="vertical" and set relativelayout match_parent